# CSV File Import/Reading - Android

Tags: android, file, csv, android-assets

Pretty short question:
I have put a .csv file in my assets folder.  My problem is that I'm unsure how to read it and store its contents in an array-like form that I can pass to a function that then loops through the contents.

So, basically I want something like (pseudo code):

```
VariableArray var[] = new Variable (get the file contents);
performFunction(var[]);
```

How I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this to get an InputStream to your file in assets.

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open(fileName);
```

Then you just need to make a reader and loop through the file until the end of it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  I just had to surround this with a try|catch, and add the import for inputstream.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the [JavaCSV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/) library to deal with CSV formats. There are a lot of things it can accomplish in very few lines of code.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't what I need.  I already have the CSV file.  I can store it in Java from my computer.  However, I'm not sure how to do this with an android phone.  People have been telling me to put it in my 'assets' folder, but I have no idea how to tell the program to read the file from there.

Comment: Tim's answer was all I was looking for, but you thank you for trying to help me too.