# How to put Excel results(values) into Eclipse Android activity

Tags: android, eclipse, excel, android-layout

I am undergraduate and nearly have no basics on Java knowledge. I had been helping my friends to design an app to display his results with wireless. Previously, he had a list of parameters and id numbers about 100 rows and I keyed in 1 row by 1 row with using

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="ABG_0"
        android:id="@+id/textView111"
        android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView211"
        android:text="2049"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"></TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView311"
        android:text="333"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"></TextView>
</TableRow>
```

Recently, he updated his parameters list to about 350 rows, so is there a way to put those parameters and ids (which was saved in an excel file) to the android activity of eclipse so that the parameters were stored locally and internally inside the app.(displayed on activity xml)

I had been searching for methods to put in excel results into the table in android eclipse but hardly found any feasible method. Please give any advice if you do. Thank you.

Comment: Don't store them in XML.  Save Excel as CSV, read into SQLite, use adapter and list view to show in app.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you not to put it directly into your XML view file, you should :

1. Store your values in a .csv file that you can put in your app in the
   assets dir,
2. Read your .csv file
   ([CSV File Import/Reading - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860439/csv-file-import-reading-android))
3. Use a listView to display your values (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html).

If you want more explanations, feel free to ask !

Comment: ya, actually why i am putting into a xml initially is because that the "333" part in the third text view above is something that have to be taken from a server continuously(keep refreshing).

Is it possible to directly put in the parameters from my fren's mysql database into android? ( He has made a database in mysql with the above parameters in it )

Comment: Hey Zeiok, how do you actually read the .csv file into android? Is there any code that I can read and modified?